# JQuery get value out of json by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I generate a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "attendees": [ 
    {
      "datum": "Tue, 11 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT", 
      "name": " Muylaert-Geleir", 
      "prename": "Alexander"
    }, 
    {
      "datum": "Wed, 12 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT", 
      "name": " Obolina", 
      "prename": "Angelina"
    }, 
    {
      "datum": "Thu, 13 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT", 
      "name": " Obolina", 
      "prename": "Angelina"
    }, 
]
}
```

How do i get the value from all keys and place it into tables? 
This is what i already got...

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

for (i = 0; i < response.attendees.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
$('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ response.attendees["name"] + '</td><td>'+ response.attendees["prename"] + '</td><td>' + response.attendees["datum"] + '</td></tr>'); 
console.log(response.attendees["name"]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, use `response.attendees[i]` for getting individual properties instead of `response.attendees`

```
$('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ response.attendees[i]["name"] + '</td><td>'+ response.attendees[i]["prename"] + '</td><td>' + response.attendees[i]["datum"] + '</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, struggled way to hard for this one

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass `dataType:json` you have to parse it with `JSON.parse` and then you can access it with `.`

```
$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    response.attendees.forEach(attendee){
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+ attendee.name + '</td><td>'+ attendee.prename + '</td><td>' + attendee.datum + '</td></tr>'); 
        console.log(attendee.name);
    }
});
```

Comment: you don't need to parse() if `settings` has correct `dataType`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the array index within the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < response.attendees.length; i++){
    console.log(i);

    console.log(response.attendees[i]["name"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are need to mention the increment value of `i` in the for loop iteration

```js
var response = {
  "attendees": [{
      "datum": "Tue, 11 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT",
      "name": " Muylaert-Geleir",
      "prename": "Alexander"
    },
    {
      "datum": "Wed, 12 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT",
      "name": " Obolina",
      "prename": "Angelina"
    },
    {
      "datum": "Thu, 13 Apr 2017 00:00:00 GMT",
      "name": " Obolina",
      "prename": "Angelina"
    },
  ]
}

for (i = 0; i < response.attendees.length; i++) {
  $('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + response.attendees[i]["name"] + '</td><td>' + response.attendees[i]["prename"] + '</td><td>' + response.attendees[i]["datum"] + '</td></tr>');
}
```

```css
table,tr,td{
border:1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding DOM elements in a loop is bad for performance. The DOM operations are one of the most expensive so instead, you should store it and add all at once

```
var attendees = response.attendees.map(function(attendee){
    return '<tr><td>'+ attendee.name + '</td><td>'+ attendee.prename + '</td><td>' + attendee.datum + '</td></tr>'
});
$('tbody').append(attendees.join(''));
```

I'm using `map` here to iterate over array create an array of strings (HTML) and at the end join them